# преобразовать текстовый файл в XML с помощью PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Как сделать преобразование текстового файла в XML с помощью PHP?
Например:есть текстовый файл см.скрин [http://prntscr.com/svpr31,и](http://prntscr.com/svpr31,%D0%B8) нужно его преобразовать в xml файл,с нужными тегами примерно так см.скрин http://prntscr.com/swp4o6.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Начните с того, чтобы задавать вопросы в том формате, как они тут приветствуются. То есть формат входных и выходных данных в виде текст а не картинок. Далее выскажите ваши соображения по решению данной задачи, и приложите ваши варианты решения, если таковые есть, но не работают, или хотя бы опишите, в чем вы видите проблему реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону SimpleXML.
Вот хорошая статья
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xmlphp1/index.html

Ну или вот:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp